# How to read a csv file from unix server in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ftp

I need to create spark dataframe from csv file which is located in my UNIX server.

I tried like below,

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("demo").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','True'). \
    load("ftp://USER:PASSWORD@UNIX_IP/home/user/sample.csv")

df.show(10)
```

But its throwing the error as,

**pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in user info at index 32**

Could anyone help me to resolve this. How we need to refer the ftp location in pyspark? Do we need to include any other library for this?

Comment: [this medium blog](https://medium.com/@somanathsankaran/accessing-lookup-files-from-web-ftp-servers-with-pyspark-da155ee0448b) talks about reading files from web servers and ftp servers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `addFile` method like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

sc.addFile("ftp://user:pwd@host:port/home/user/sample.csv")
spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("sample.csv")).show()
```

To test it, you could use a public ftp like:

```scala
sc.addFile("ftp://anonymous:anonymous@ftp.gnu.org/README")
spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("README")).show(2)
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 _c0|                 _c1|
+--------------------+--------------------+
| This is ftp.gnu.org| the FTP server o...|
|NOTICE (Updated O...|                null|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

In python:

```py
from pyspark import SparkFiles

sc.addFile('ftp://user:pwd@host:port/home/user/sample.csv')
spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get('sample.csv')).show()
```

Comment: Do we need to have any specific jar for this? Am getting "No supported file system" error